# How to draw a stripline diagonally using MSChart?

Tags: c#, mschart

Tweaking MS Charts. I have successfully draw a dynamic chart but need to draw a line (Yellow) across the chart. How will i draw (yellow) line. I have X and Y values.
[image]

Comment: Looks like a `LineAnnotation`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example you can play with:

```
// we create a general LineAnnotation, ie not Vertical or Horizontal:
LineAnnotation lan = new LineAnnotation();

// we use Axis scaling, not chart scaling
lan.IsSizeAlwaysRelative = false;

lan.LineColor = Color.Yellow;
lan.LineWidth = 5;

// the coordinates of the starting point in axis measurement
lan.X = 3.5d;
lan.Y = 0d;
// the size: 
lan.Width = -3.5d;
lan.Height = 5.5d;

// looks like we need an anchor point, no matter which..
lan.AnchorDataPoint = yourSeries.Points[0];

// now we can add the LineAnnotation;
chart1.Annotations.Add(lan);
```